# Syntax: use second argument leaving the first argument as default in a macro

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, syntax, arguments, renewcommand

I use this command to abbreviate my notation

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Lp}{O{p}O{\mathbb{R}^d}O{[- \infty, \infty]}}%
   {L^{#1}(#2, #3)}
```

I've set one default for each argument, in most cases I need just to change the first argument, like this

```
\Lp[1]
```

Sometimes though, I need to change just the second, like this

```
\Lp[p][E]
```

This feels redundant to me, I would like to avoid rewriting the first argument and just leaving it as the default I set (actually this is not just a "first argument problem", in some cases I need to change just the third argument and so on). A notation that feels natural to me is

```
\Lp[][E]
\Lp[1][][\mathbb{R}]
```

where by "`[]`" I mean "assign the default value", but by doing so I trivially get an empty space.
I would like to know if there's a syntax for doing so and, if not, what's the best practice to accomplish it (I guess one should use some "if-then-else" inside the `\NewDocumentCommand`).

Comment: it is best to avoid adjacent positional optional arguments for that reason. latex commands usually arrange the options are separated by mandatory, eg `\usepackage[opts]{name}[date]`  or use key-value `\includegraphics[height=..,width=..]{file}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classical example of a command with multiple consecutive optional arguments is

```
\parbox[<outer alignment>][<vertical dimension>][<inner alignment>]{<width>}{<text>}
```

where the third optional argument makes sense only if the second one is present. Likely, the syntax would have been better if the second and third optional arguments were after `{<width>}`, but it has been like that almost forever.

In your case the arguments are completely independent of one another, so your sequence of optional arguments has the clumsiness you see.

Defining a key-value syntax is better for your case and it's not really difficult.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { fral/lp }
 {
  e .tl_set:N = \l__fral_lp_exponent_tl,
  s .tl_set:N = \l__fral_lp_space_tl,
  i .tl_set:N = \l__fral_lp_interval_tl,
  e .initial:n = p,
  s .initial:n = \mathbb{R}^d,
  i .initial:n = {[-\infty,\infty]},
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\Lp}{O{}}
 {
  \group_begin: % not to clobber initial values
  \keys_set:nn { fral/lp } { #1 }
  L^{\l__fral_lp_exponent_tl}(\l__fral_lp_space_tl,\l__fral_lp_interval_tl)
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\Lp$

$\Lp[e=1]$

$\Lp[e=2,s=X,i={[1,2]}]$

$\Lp[i={[1,2]},e=2,s=X]$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: they were added in 2e, and are not after width so that in minipage a leading [ in the body of a 2.09 minipage did not complicate updating to 2e.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I can understand the reason. Too bad times were not mature for key-value syntax.

Comment: I think this syntax perfectly suits my situation, thanks! (Because, you're right, the three arguments are independent from each other)

Comment: I forgot, can I reuse the "fral/lp syntax" for another command? For example, I've got a similar command
`\NewDocumentCommand{\normLp}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { fral/lp } { #1 }
  \norm{#2}_{L^{\l__fral_lp_exponent_tl}(\l__fral_lp_space_tl,\l__fral_lp_interval_tl)}
  \group_end:
 }`
It should take a mandatory argument that goes inside `\norm{}` (I'm not sure about the "#2" part)

Comment: @Fral Are you defining `\norm` with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`?

Comment: `\norm` comes from the physics package (that's all I know)

Comment: @Fral I usually recommend *not* using `physics`.

Comment: @egreg at the moment my code is quite dependent on that package, in the future I'll try to avoid it (are there any alternatives?). Anyway I've came out with this: `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\mynorm}{\lVert}{\rVert}` and `\NewDocumentCommand{\mynormLp}{O{}m}
{
    \group_begin:   \keys_set:nn { fral/lp } { #1 } \mynorm{#2}\c_math_subscript_token{L^{\l__fral_lp_exponent_tl}(\l__fral_lp_space_tl,\l__fral_lp_interval_tl)}
    \group_end:
}`
It seems to work, thanks!